# Rail AssociationTypeMismatch, how to convert string to object before update/create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Have to say I didn't really search for a solution because I'm not aware of what I should search for.

This is the case:

I have an object (NewsItem) which has a relation called Tags.

```
class NewsItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tags
end
```

I get these tags as an array of strings when submitting an update/create form causing this error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch 
Tag expected, got String
```

Now before rails is going to save them as a relation I need to convert these strings to Tags like so:

```
params[:tags].each do |tag|
    Tags.find_or_create_by_name(tag)
end
```

This way rails gets it desired tags.

I know I can put this in the controller, but I need it on the model..

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put a method on the model that takes a string parameter and do the same thing?

Comment: Rails automatically assigns these tag attributes on update_attributes. I don't understand where I should put a method on on this model that converts these tags before Rails tries to update the relation..

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "where"; create a method and call it from the controller.

Comment: I understand. That's a good solution. Is there a way to automatically do this before update? It seems rails is throwing the TypeMismatch before any before filter is called, but I'm not sure.

Comment: There's a number of options. You could create an `attr_accessor` attribute, set it, and process it before save, I suppose. The issue is that you'd need to check the model's existing tags as well.

Comment: Great! I think I'm getting somewhere with the attr_accessor. I'll post the solution when I got it.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be adding a new method like `tags_list` that does the same of what you're doing in the controller, as in:

```
class NewsItem < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :tags

  def tags_list
    self.tags.map { |tag| tag.name }
  end

  def tags_list=(tag_names)
    self.tags = tag_names.map do |tag|
      Tag.find_or_create_by_name(tag)
    end
  end

end
```

Then, at your view, you will have to change the form field name from `tags` to `tags_list` also. This is what common plugins like `acts_as_taggable_on` usually do.

Comment: This is what I'm working on now, only simpler. I've created an attr_accessor and a before_validation, but this is a better way. I'll go for this solution! Thanks!